# WKWebView doesn't load .archive file if some web page has been loaded previously

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I faced some strange behaviour of `WKWebView`.

If I load .webarchive file using `loadFileURL(_ URL: URL, allowingReadAccessTo readAccessURL: URL)` right after initialising webView, it works well, but when I load some web content using `load(_ request: URLRequest)` and then trying to load file with previous mentioned method then I get error in `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)` delegate method:

`[ProcessSwapping] 0x10af34160 - ProvisionalPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: pageID = 1, frameID = 1, navigationID = 4`

I solved it temporarily with recreating `WKWebView` instance in case loading URL with `file` scheme when current webView url scheme is not `file`. In my opinion this is unacceptable.

During researching I had a guess that this behaviour is about permission to some resources. And even `loadFileURL` method has `readAccessURL` parameter it probably isn't updated.

Comment: I'm just now hitting this; any news?

Comment: nope, I ended up with to independent webViews, one is for local files and other - for remote resources.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I've understood your question properly.

It seems like your "webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)" function treats it as a http/https URL. So, you should specify it inside the function that it's like a http/https URL.